# why I am getting error as "This webpage has a redirect loop"

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have one site in drupal and abruptly site hit is giving error as "This webpage has a redirect loop".

The webpage at `http://example.com/install.php` has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
Learn more about this problem.

> Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many
>   redirects.

can any one tell where I am going wrong?

Comment: Have a look at the network tab of the console; you'll see that the page is either trying to redirect back to itself, or it's bouncing between other pages that eventually redirect back to the original page.

Comment: No luck what? What does the network tab show?

Answer (score 1):

Try to upload a static HTML file to the same directory and try to access this file via HTTP. If it gives you the same error, then it's the directory permission.

The common cause is that you don't have the permission to browse the folder. You can fix it by giving `execute permission for everyone`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message. I found [this issue on drupal.org](https://drupal.org/node/1093464) from which I got the idea to look for `install.php` that had been deleted by Softaculous (automated installation software).

Copying `install.php` from a freshly downloaded package solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just recently had this issue today working on a dev site. Only the front page was resulting in a "Too Many Redirects" error, all other pages for the site worked correctly. Turned out to be an issue related to the hosting, turned off caching and everything worked out fine.